# How to count row by two fields and group by id as a subquery in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table like this:

| id | user_id | converted_from | converted_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | en | ro |
| 2 | 1 | en | ro |
| 3 | 1 | ro | en |
| 4 | 2 | en | ro |
| 5 | 2 | en | ro |
| 6 | 2 | ro | en |
| 7 | 2 | ro | en |

[image: Table image]

I tried like this:

```php
$data = UserDocument::select(DB::raw('(SELECT convert_from, convert_to, COUNT(convert_from) FROM user_documents udoc where udoc.user_id = user_id  GROUP BY convert_from, convert_to) as languages'))
                    ->groupby('user_id')
                    ->get();
```

I expected result like this:

| user_id | languages |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | en -> ro : 2 |
|  | ro -> en : 1 |
|  |  |
| 2 | en -> ro : 2 |
|  | ro -> en : 2 |

Expected result

Comment: You are grouping the select result by user_id 2 times. Can you till us what is the result now?

Comment: having this error:  Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select (SELECT convert_from, convert_to, COUNT(convert_from) FROM user_documents udoc where udoc.user_id = user_id GROUP BY convert_from, convert_to) as languages from `user_documents` group by `user_id`) as `aggregate_table`)

Comment: SELECT convert_from, convert_to, COUNT(convert_from) as languages FROM documents udoc where udoc.user_id = $user_id   GROUP BY convert_from, convert_to;

Comment: this is not giving result per user_id.

Comment: I thing the best way is to add methods in the Models to do the the calculation for you.  
Any way i test the bellow query in my end and its give all data you need.

SELECT user_id,convert_from, convert_to, COUNT(convert_from) as languages FROM documents udoc where udoc.user_id = user_id GROUP BY user_id,convert_from, convert_to;

Comment: Please update the question by adding theSQL error in your question @S.M.MahfuzurRahman